# multiplication of 2 * 2 matix

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

```
m = [[3,5], [2,-2]]
n = [[-1,0], [11,3]]
ans = [[0,0], [0,0]]
for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m[i])):
        ans[i][j] = (m[i][j] * n[i][j]) + (m[i][len(m)-j-1] * n[len(n)-i-1][j])
        print(ans[i][j], end="\t")
    print()
```

now my answer is wrong and I cannot come up with another solution.

Comment: This is normal 'matrix multiplication'? Also, can you use numpy?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to populate a[i][j], then each element is a sum of the product of the i'th row from m and the j'th column of n column elements. Written in python code as a sum this would be:

```
a[i][j] = sum( m[i][s]*n[s][j] for s in range( len(m[i]) ) )
```

Since you're using 2x2 matrices it doesn't really matter, but the final dimensions of your matrix will depend on the sizes of m and n.

In your example you've tried to write this sum explicitly. In that case instead of summing over s, we would write out each term for the corresponding s values. The following expression has two terms.

```
a[i][j] = m[i][0]*n[0][j] + m[i][1]*n[1][j]
```

It seems like you're trying to be general, but you cannot be without creating a sum/loop because regardless of the dimensions the way you have written it will only have two terms.

Comment: Thanks but sorry. I couldn't quite understand your part of code. I know I'm being general but could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan " I'm being general..." you are not being general, you are explicitly writing the code for a 2x2 matrix. You have `len(m)-j-1` but the length of m is always 2, so you have `1 - j`. If you wanted to do 3x3, then your equation could never work since a 3x3 matrix would require adding 3 terms. The code I have written would replace the line ans[i][j].

Comment: Okaay. Thanks but still, could you explain what your line is doing as I am just a beginner.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan What don't you understand? They python, or how matrix multiplication works? The first line uses python's sum function, I created an generator object using `range( len(m[i]))` that produces s=0 and s=1. It is equivalent to the second line.

Comment: Okaay . Now I understood. Thanks 